# KUTE.js svg paths not morphing

Tags: javascript, svg, path, morphing

[Here is a codepen i made.](http://codepen.io/RUIFERNANDE5/pen/AXzbEN)

As you can see, the paths are not morphing.
I've already jumped to the conclusion the problem is within the *svg* itself, they are not morphing. 
What could it be the problem? The shapes are quite simple, all have the same size and anchors and, as it says on [kute.js documentation](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js/svg.html), "closed shapes (their d attribute ends with z)."

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >
    <path id="n1" fill="orangered" d="M62,7.5l210,20l30,230l-290-60L62,7.5z"/>
    <path id="n2" style="visibility:hidden" d="M0,7.5l315,32l-31,189l-280,31L0,7.5"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: I see morphing on the codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version [fixes](https://github.com/thednp/kute.js/blob/master/kute-svg.js#L77) the problem. The plugin didn't handle the case when the two polygons have same number of points.

The code in issue

```
  if ( s.length !== e.length ){
    arL = Math.max(s.length,e.length);
    if ( arL === e.length) { sm = s; lg = e; } else { sm = e; lg = s; }
    sml = sm.length;

    smp = S.cP('M'+sm.join('L')+'z'); len = smp.getTotalLength() / arL;
    for (var i=0; i<arL; i++){
      tl = smp.getPointAtLength(len*i);
      cs = S.gCP(len,tl,sm);
      nsm.push( [ cs[0], cs[1] ] );
    }

    if (arL === e.length) { e1 = lg; s1 = nsm; } else { s1 = lg; e1 = nsm; }
  } else { // here we know the paths have same number of points
    s1 = s; e1 = e;
  }
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/thednp/pen/YWbpJo).